# Setter not changing the value of the variable in my class

Tags: java, android, variables, constructor, setter

I have been working at it for some time and looking it up online however can't find anything.
I'm trying to work out why the Log I created under
`Player.Update()` is always returning 0 whereas the Log in my Setter is reporting the right values.

The relevant code should be below.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    //Accelerometer
    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer;

    private static int DIRECTION_STATIONARY = 0;
    private static int DIRECTION_DOWN = 1;
    private static int DIRECTION_LEFT = 2;
    private static int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 3;
    private static int DIRECTION_UP = 4;

    Player player;
    GameView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new GameView(this);
        player = new Player();
        setContentView(gameView);

        //Accelerometer
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if (sensorEvent.values[0] < -1){
                player.setDirection(DIRECTION_UP);
                //Log.d("onSensorChanged", ""+ player.getDirection());
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[0] > 1){
                player.setDirection(DIRECTION_DOWN);
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[1] < -1){
                player.setDirection(DIRECTION_LEFT);
            }
            else if (sensorEvent.values[1] > 1){
                player.setDirection(DIRECTION_RIGHT);
            }
            else{
                player.setDirection(DIRECTION_STATIONARY);
            }
            //Log.d("Player Update", "X:" +sensorEvent.values[0]+ " Y:" +sensorEvent.values[1]+ " Z:" +sensorEvent.values[2] + " Direction: " + direction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import ...

public class Player {

    private Bitmap sprite;
    private int x, y, speed;

    //Animation Variables
    private static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 4;
    private static final int SPRITE_COLUMNS = 4;
    private int currentFrame, width, height, srcY, srcX, direction;
    Rect src, dst;

    //Static Directions
    private static int DIRECTION_STATIONARY = 0;
    private static int DIRECTION_DOWN = 1;
    private static int DIRECTION_LEFT = 2;
    private static int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 3;
    private static int DIRECTION_UP = 4;

    GameView gameView;

    public Player (Context context, GameView gameView){
        this.gameView = gameView;

        x = 100;
        y = 500;

        speed = 30;

        sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.player);

        width = sprite.getWidth() / SPRITE_COLUMNS;
        height = sprite.getHeight() / SPRITE_ROWS;

    }

    public Player() {

    }

    public void Update() {

        Log.d("Player | Update", "" + direction);
        if (direction == DIRECTION_UP){
            y -= speed;
        }
        else if (direction == DIRECTION_DOWN){
            y += speed;
        }
        else if (direction == DIRECTION_RIGHT){
            x += speed;
        }
        else if (direction == DIRECTION_LEFT){
            x -= speed;
        }
        else if (direction == 0){

        }
    }

    public void UpdateAnim(){

        currentFrame = ++currentFrame % SPRITE_COLUMNS;
        srcX = currentFrame * width;

        if (direction == DIRECTION_RIGHT){
            srcY = 2 * height;
        }
        else if (direction == DIRECTION_LEFT){
            srcY = 1 * height;
        }
        if (direction == DIRECTION_DOWN){
            srcY = 0 * height;
        }
        else if (direction == DIRECTION_UP){
            srcY = 3 * height;
        }

        src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
        dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }


    public Rect getSrc(){
        return src;
    }

    public Rect getDst(){
        return dst;
    }

    public Bitmap getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }

    public void setDirection(int mainDirection) {
        this.direction = mainDirection;
        Log.d("Setter", "" + direction);
    }
}
```

**GameView**

```
package com.Frenchie.AnimatedSprite;

import ...

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Thread thread;

    Player player;


    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        player = new Player(context, this);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Update();
            DrawCanvas();
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        player.Update();
        player.UpdateAnim();
        Control();
    }

    private void DrawCanvas() {

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            canvas.drawBitmap(player.getSprite(), player.getSrc(), player.getDst(), null);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        } else {
            Log.d("Run", "Surface Invalid");
        }
    }

    private void Control() {
        try {
            thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: You never get any values from the object, when do you try to get values and they are incorrect?

Comment: They are frequently called from another thread and display about 5 times a second. Both Update and UpdateAnim methods are called from a class called gameView.

Comment: Prolly it is different Player instance

Comment: I don't see you passing passing the player object to the GameView, you might be using a different instance, that's why you don't see the values changing, they are different objects.

Comment: Player is not thread safe if you are using one reference to Player in two or more threads.

Comment: I will upload the gameView class too. In your case @DwB how would I go about resolving that issue?